# Generating an automatic student registration number using php

Tags: php

I want to generate an automatic student registration number composed of "ID N0.","INTAKE" 
and the current year, each time a student is recorded.

EX: KIAC 0013/INTAKE 4/2019.
But the problem is that the intake value which is 4 only increments once and i want it to increment each time a new intake starts.

I wasn't able to increment the intake value 
as a new intake starts,in march and in september. so this means that students 
for the september intake will be having "KIAC 0013/INTAKE 4/2019" as registration number 
and those of march 2020 "KIAC 0013/INTAKE 5/2020" again 
september 2020 "KIAC 0013/INTAKE 6/2020" and so on... but the intake value would still be 5 for september 2020 also.. this means it increments no more, the code below is a sample code and it doesn't insert into the database i was just testing for the result..

```
<?php
$k = "KIAC";
$id = "0013/INTAKE";
$month = date("m");
$year = date("Y");

if($month == '3'){
 $intake = 3;
 $intake++;  
 echo $k . "&nbsp;" . $id . "&nbsp;" . $intake. "/". $year;
}

else if($month == '9'){
 $intake = 3;
 $intake++;  
 echo $k . "&nbsp;" . $id . "&nbsp;" . $intake. "/". $year;
}

else{
 $intake = 3;
 echo $k . "&nbsp;" . $id . "&nbsp;" . $intake. "/". $year;
}
?>
```

I expected the output to be  "KIAC 0013/INTAKE 4/2019." and the intake value 
would change as a new intake starts.

Comment: I cannot understand your question. How about two lists of dates and registration numbers? One showing what your code does now, and the other what you would want it to do.

Comment: Why `$intake = 3;
 $intake++;  ` ? Could you not just write `$intake = 4;`

Comment: oops sorry $intake = 4;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understod your question, but maybe you could do something like this:

```
$k = "KIAC";
$id = "0013/INTAKE";
$month = date("m");
$year = date("Y");

$base_year = 2019; // Set a base when the intakes started

$intake = intval($year) - $base_year; // This will increase for every year

$increase_with = $intake++;

if($month == '3'){
  $intake += $increase_with;
  echo $k . " " . $id . " " . $intake. "/". $year;
}
else if($month == '9'){
  $increase_with++;
  $intake += $increase_with;
  echo $k . " " . $id . " " . $intake. "/". $year;
}
```

*Edited to make intake number unique.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to write condition in IF so between march to august it will increase 1 and after September intake it will increase with 2.

```
 <?php
              $k = "KIAC";
              $id = "0013/INTAKE";
              $month = date("m");
              $year = date("Y");
              $base_year = 2016;
              $intake = intval($year) - $base_year;
              if ($month == 3) {
                  $intake += 1;
                   echo $k . " " . $id . " " . $intake . "/" . $year;
               } else if($month == 9) {
                    $intake += 2;
                    echo $k . "enter code here " . $id . " " . $intake . "/" . $year;
               }else{
                    echo $k . "&nbsp;" . $id . "&nbsp;" . $intake. "/". $year;
               }
            ?>
```